# Packet for query is too large (4,739,923 > 65,535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable

Tags: java, mysql, spring

This Spring app is connecting to an Ubuntu hosted MySQL database on my local VM. Running the app gives this error. I have changed the max_allowed_packet value both in my.cnf, and mysql.cnf.

I have even ran SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet within the server. After every method of changing this value, checking the variable('SHOW VARIABLES LIKE') after a MySQL restart always returns around 67000000, no matter what I set it to (which I would think is enough).

I've also tried changing the dependency versions.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class PersonController{
    @GetMapping(value = "/home")
    public String getAllPeople(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**Main (SQL command):**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication implements CommandLineRunner{
    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM people";
        int ans = jdbcTemplate.update(sql);
        if(ans>0) System.out.println("new table created");  
    }
}
```

**application.properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.200:3333/test
spring.datasource.username = boss
spring.datasource.password = StrongPass123!
```

**Pom.xml (relevant dependencies):**

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
     <groupId>mysql</groupId>
     <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
     <version>8.0.29</version>
</dependency>
```

**Trace:**

```
2022-06-29 19:44:04.268 ERROR 14664 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
    
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (4,739,923 > 65,535). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:107) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.29.jar:8.0.29]
     ...
```

Comment: _I have changed the max_allowed_packet value both in my.cnf, and mysql.cnf_ – have you also verified if the value in your `.cnf` file actually was picked up by the running database? Try: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`

Comment: @Kaan after changing [mysql] to [mysqld] in the .cnf file, and restarting mysql, it remembers and shows what I set it to(1000M). But I get the exact same error.

Comment: *I have even ran SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet within the server.* This sets dynamic value for a server which effects new connections settings only (not effects on existing connections) and which is actual until the serever restaring. To make this setting permanent you must edit either options file or service command line.

Comment: I had the same error with the same bytes numbers, my mistake was I was using a mysql connector for a postgres database